# Mysql InnoDB Deadlock on INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql, kotlin, innodb, jdbi, jdbi3-core

I have a table with the following structure -

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` varchar(38) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `creation_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  `update_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_unique` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In my application, I first open a transaction before inserting to this table because after the insert to this table I have to insert to another one. When I have 2 threads, 2 transactions are created and sometime they try to insert the same set of names to this table (however with different ids cause it's GUID). Each one of the transactions tries to insert its set of values one by one. Also, each transaction sorts the values to be inserted by name, so basically the 2 transaction should try to insert the same names with the same order

In that situation I want 1 of the transactions to be successful and the other one to not do anything so I used INSERT IGNORE -

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO some_table
           (
             id,
             name
           )
           values (
             :id,
             :name
           )
```

Unfortunately, I get deadlocks when 2 threads try to insert the same set of names to this table.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this or why this happens?
In InnoDB logs I saw it's related to gap locks but I couldn't figure out more.

Comment: In order to resolve the problem, you need to check the deadlock related data in innodb status monitor. It is likely that you need to insert the data in specific order to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: @shadow I forgot to mention, each transaction orders the inserts by name. So basically the 2 transaction in the deadlock should try to insert the same names in the same order. But still it doesn't work and I get deadlock

Comment: Then make sure that the two threads do not try to insert the same set of records at the same time.

Comment: The real problem is trying to insert a row with two unique keys, where both keys are generated outside the transaction.  `AUTO_INCREMENT` avoids the problem because you _do not_ include it in the `INSERT`; instead it is a side effect of the `INSERT`.  Rethink your use of guids, at least guids that are not _generated_ as part of the `INSERT`.